# Get latest entries from two other tables per record

Tags: django

I have these three classes:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
     stock_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
     vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
     year = models.ForeignKey(Year)
     ... (several other fields declared here)

class VehicleMileage(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    odometer_reading = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_time_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today, editable=False)

class VehicleMileage(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_time_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today, editable=False)
```

What I want to do is get all vehicles with their latest mileage and price from the respective classes, and all this in one query.  Currently I'm getting all three separately, then inserting what I want into a dictionary item for template use, like this:

```
vehicle_list = Vehicle.objects.all().values('vin', 'stock_number', 'year__year')
vehicles = []

for vehicle in vehicle_list:
    lst = {}
    latest_mileage = VehicleMileage.objects.filter(vehicle__stock_number =
                        stock_number).values('odometer_reading').order_by(
                        '-date_time_added')[0]
    latest_price = VehiclePrice.objects.filter(vehicle__stock_number = 
                        stock_number).values('price').order_by(
                        '-date_time_added')[0]
    lst['stock_number'] = vehicle['stock_number']
    lst['year'] = vehicle['year__year']
    lst['vin'] = vehicle['vin']
    lst['mileage'] = latest_mileage['odometer_reading']
    lst['price'] = latest_price['price']

    vehicles.append(lst)
```

Is there a better way I can retrieve what I want and have the least amount of queries running?  Currently the above code needs about 100 queries.

Comment: I've figured out how to do it via SQL, and I think I'll stick with this solution for now unless someone knows how to do it via the Django ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in django orm. You can use the lowercase name of the of the model in this case `vehiclemileage` and `vehicleprice` with the `Vehicle` model to get the result set.

This is how the query looks:

```
vehicles_with_latest_mileage_price = Vehicle.objects.values('vehiclemileage__odometer_reading','vehicleprice__price','vin','stock_number','year__year').order_by('-vehiclemileage__date_time_added','-vehicleprice__date_time_added')
```

This should return latest vehicles with its relevant price and mileage resulting in one query and returning one dataset.

sorry but you'll have to scroll to see the entire query.

Comment: Excellent!  I'd already implemented the SQL option, but this is good!  There are some places I'll need the ORM's funtionality.  NP on the scrolling :)